# TS Decorators: Generate properties visible by the compiler

Tags: typescript, decorator

Is it possible to define some properties in a property decorator and have those new properties understood by the TS compiler ?

In the code below, the `aExtra` property is accessible through the named property accessor `v['aExtra']` or through a cast to any `(<any>a).aFieldExtra`, but not directly `v.aExtra` as the compiler does not see it (Property does not exist).

Is there any possibility to make this extra property be visible by the compiler ?

```
function withExtra(target: any, fieldName: string) {
 Object.defineProperty(target, fieldName + 'Extra', {
    get: function (): String {
      return this[fieldName] + 'Extra'; // <EnumValue[]>this._beanInternalService.getEnumValues(enumType);
    },
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true
  });
}

class A {
  @withExtra
  a: string;
}

describe('test Extra', () => {
  it('addsExtra', () => {
    const v = new A();
    v.a = 'a';
    expect(v['aExtra']).toEqual('aExtra'); // Works as expected
    expect((<any>v).aExtra).toEqual('aExtra'); // Compiles, but not very nice
    // does not compile :
    // expect(v.aExtra).toEqual('aExtra');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, decorators do not change the structure of the class that TypeScript sees.  There is an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) about it, but it's just a "suggestion" without a proposal.  Even if you had this, I doubt you could get the behavior you want automatically, since the added property names are dynamic.  There is currently [no way](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16392) to append string literals at the type level, so you can't even describe the transformation you're doing:

```
// without Append<A extends string, B extends string>, you can't type this:

function appendExtra<T extends string>(originalKey: T): Append<T,'Extra'> {
  return originalKey+'Extra';
}
```

---

The easiest workaround I can think of for now is just to annotate the class manually as you decorate it:

```
class A {
  @withExtra
  a: string;
  aExtra: string; //added by decorator
}
```

which will (of course) seen by the compiler.

---

You *could* try using a mixin instead of a decorator, but it would be even more annoying and just as "not nice" as the casting you're doing in the question.

Hope that helps!  Good luck.

Comment: It does help, even if your answer says there is no "nice" solution today. I believe I will manual add the aExtra field's declaration. Thanks for the link to the issue